# Can web or proxy servers detect requester's OS without User-Agent?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, user-agent, http-proxy

I'm crawling web pages using the Python library `scrapy` with HTTP proxy servers collected from the web. Since I have several machines that operate on various operating systems, I'm testing the same `scrapy` spider on my machines. I expected that all the machines will show the same performance, because they send request in the same form, using randomly selected proxy servers from the large pool, but the spider running on `Windows` machine out outperforms others.

I didn't expect any specific success rate, since many of the proxy servers are out of service. However, I also didn't expect that the success rates can be different depending on the operating systems as follows.

- Windows 10: 16.85%
- Ubuntu 18: 3.84%

Now, I'm suspecting that there must be some tools that compare `User-Agent` of HTTP header with the client's real OS, since I'm using the following `User-Agent` throughout all the requests independent to the real operating systems.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
```

1. Would it be possible for web/proxy servers to inspect HTTP `User-Agent`?
2. If so, how can I avoid it?

Comment: The way your client negotiates encryption, the order, case and value format of your headers… There are various low-level ways which may be used to find details about the underlying system.